# Possible to read text record from NFC tag within Shortcuts?

Tags: iphone, shortcuts-app, nfc

Which Shortcut action reads an NFC text record?

**Example:**

- NFC tag is written with a text record: `Office`
- Shortcut trigger: `NFC`
- Within the automation steps, how can I read the `Office` value of the text record?

Answer (score 2):

Shortcuts cannot currently read NFC tags. They can only trigger an action based on the tag's unqiue ID.  So you can have a tag launch a specific Shortcut but that Shortcut cannot read any additional data from the tag (currently).  If you write your own app it can fully read and write the tag data including embedding records like URLs that can be suggested without any app required.

Answer (score 1):

I believe since iOS 15 you are able to. I just did a test and was able to write three different tags with a shortcut trigger and text.

I wrote the following to the tag:

shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=Test&input=text&text=Lounge

I then create the following shortcut to speak the text which from the tag:

[image: image of shortcuts steps]

I wrote a few more tags with different text and test and it correctly scan and read them out.

I am currently using to create automation triggers for Homekit.

Comment: I think that was not the question of the original poster.  The question was (imho) how to read out the text from a text record from the NFC chip itself. And I think that’s still (April 2023, iOS 16.4.1) not possible like Pat Niemeyer answered. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

There is a collection of Shortcuts actions called ["Toolbox Pro for Shortcuts"](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/toolbox-pro-for-shortcuts/id1476205977) available on Apple's App store.

It contains a "Scan NFC" action that can read or write text to an NFC tag.
A downloadable shortcut that demonstrates how to use this action is provided through the app's documentation.

This action is part of "Toolbox Pro Premium", which can be unlocked with an in-app purchase (currently 5.99 USD)